# What is the name of class for "self.title"?

Tags: objective-c, navigationbar, searchbar

I have modified the Apple sample code "TableSearch", but there is one thing I managed not to figure out by myself. How to make self.title to be fixed when I click onto the search bar?

I dont want self.title to fly away when I click on the search bar.

---

EDIT 17 august

The issue is resolved, so I removed the two pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify this behavior when using a `UISearchDisplayController` (which the sample does). Use a `UISearchBar` directly and set it as the `headerView` of your table view.

Comment: Thanks. self.title is an instance of UIViewController, right? I want the search bar to be below self.title and visible all the time  even when I scroll tableview, so headerView cant be used.

Comment: Then make a `UIViewController` that contains a search bar and a table view below it. The `title` property of `UIViewController` is an `NSString`, but that doesn't matter much for what you want to achieve.

Comment: I see. Should it contain the pair searchbar and tableview, not searchbar and tableviewcontroller?

Comment: Of course, I understand now :) It is beneficial to use searchbar and tableview in uiviewcontroller :)